# How to use spark session in a python function?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i want to use Spark Session with in a python method but getting error "SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063." i am trying to run sparksession from a method which is called by another method, on running in main function the code is working.

```
    def hive_company(tuples):
        spark.sql("insert into table hive_table values(\'%s\',\'%s\')" % tuples)

    def data_set(data):
        company = data["EMPLOYER_NAME"]
        soc_name = data["SOC_NAME"]
        if (company == 'XYZ LIMITED'):
            comp_tuple = (company, soc_name)
            hive_visa.hive_company(comp_tuple)
```

Error: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define SparkSession. You can try this example -

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("yarn") \
    .appName("python_func_example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value-sample-entry") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()


def python_func_example (schema, table):
    query = "select * from {}.{}"
    df = spark.sql(query.format(schema, table))
    return df


if __name__ == '__main__':
    python_func_example()
```

Comment: i have intialized the sparksession(thats not in the code). i am trying to run sparksession from a method which is called by another method.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible what you are trying to do.

Code is written and runs on the Driver with Driver sending commands like map, filter or pipe-lined such commands to the Executors, as Tasks, to run against the partition(s) on that Executor.

The message tells you that is not possible.